# .htaccess fix for a pretty permalink in PHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permalinks

Maybe I'm going about this in the wrong way, but I have some pages in our homegrown CMS that I want to convert to using pretty permalinks. Currently, their page URLs look this this:

http://ourdomain.com/articles/?permalink=blah-blah-blah

I want to convert these to:

http://ourdomain.com/articles/blah-blah-blah

I have a column in the db for permalinks, that when the article is created, automatically converts the title to a permalink.

How would I write the rewrite rule to accomplish this? Is this even the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

If there's nothing in the query string you can omit `QSA`:

```
RewriteRule articles/(.+) articles/?permalink=$1 [QSA,L,B]
```

Comment: Hmm. That didn't work. But what did was using this .htaccess code:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /articles/view/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /articles/view/index.php [L]
1,L]
</IfModule>


...and then getting the permalink through $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], trimming out the unneeded portions and filtering through mysql_real_escape_string, and using that as my query string.