# How to change permalink?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, permalinks

how do i change permalink of my url

http://www.example.com/index.php?id=230

to

http://www.example.com/index/230

Answer (score 3):

See e.g. [".htaccess fix for a pretty permalink in PHP?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356173/htaccess-fix-for-a-pretty-permalink-in-php). Also, you should be able to find loads of tutorials for [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) (and [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930789/htaccess-pretty-user-profile-urls) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265898/mod-rewrite-php-and-the-htaccess-file)).

Try out:

```
RewriteRule ^index/([0-9]+)$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: @Raghs OK, did you turn `RewriteModule On`? If yes, `mod_rewrite` is probably not enabled. Try a [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) to verify. It is [possible](http://textpattern.com/weblog/135/partly-messy-clean-urls-without-modrewrite-experimental) without `mod_rewrite`, too (but is harder to get right).

Comment: @jensgram i need to update permalinks

http://www.example.info/index.php?wiki=india
i want to change it to 
http://www.example.com/wiki/india

I have this sample code in my htaccess but its not working

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index/([0-9a-z]+)$ index.php?wiki=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: @Raghs Just to make sure that we're talking about the same: You have changed the rendering of your permalinks from `index.php?wiki=india` to `index/india`, right? And now you need the server to convert *incoming requests* for e.g. `index/india` to `index.php?wiki=india`?

Comment: @jensgram ya ryt. i need help about tat. Thanks for ur help!

Comment: @Raghs OK, then I guess we'll need you to post the full `.htaccess` file. Also, try and make a `phpinfo.php` with `<?php phpinfo();` and create a `RewriteRule .* phpinfo.php?$0 [QSA,L]`. This should catch all request (*if* `mod_rewrite` works) and forward them to `phpinfo.php` where you can inspect the data.

Comment: @jensgram i am new to htaccess, i have **RewriteEngine on RewriteBase / RewriteRule ^index/([0-9a-z]+)$ index.php?wiki=$1 [QSA,L]** in my htacess.

Comment: Well, that ought to work. Now try with the phpinfo file and the rewrite rule I posted above instead. It will tell whether *anything* works.

Comment: @jensgram it dint work in godaddy hosting there is no way to access phpinfo(),but permalink works for wordpress blog hosted wit godaddy

Comment: @Raghs Hmm, I've found a few resources you may find helpful: [Godaddy Hosting mod_rewrite with .htaccess Files](http://surf11.com/entry/153/godaddy-hosting-mod-rewrite-with-htacces) and [Find the Current PHP Version and Settings in Linux Shared or Dedicated Server Account](http://help.godaddy.com/article/5073?locale=en).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [generateit](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php) to create rewrite rule for apache and if you use nginx then use [gdix](https://labs.gidix.de/nginx/) to convert apache .htaccess rule.