# Hide GET request html/php

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I'm not really sure what I'm looking for, but I know what I wanna do. Therefor it's kinda hard to search. Sorry for being stupid, the answer might be really simple.

I got a website, as of currently I take a get request like:
http://website/id=123

What I want is to have it as
http://website/123

The website then takes the value and does a bunch of stuff, but I'm not really sure how to get it like this. Is it from editing .htaccess or what?

How do I fix that? (again, sorry for being stupid)

Comment: are you saying you don't know how to get the id value from http://website/id=123   ?

Comment: No, I know how to retreive the value, just by $_GET['id'], but I want to hide the whole thing.

Comment: @Tyler OP is asking about URL rewrites surely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically for you condition try this..

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php?id=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

See e.g. "[.htaccess fix for a pretty permalink in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356173/htaccess-fix-for-a-pretty-permalink-in-php)". Also, you should be able to find lots of tutorials for mod_rewrite (and related questions).

Try out:

```
RewriteRule ^index/([0-9]+)$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Best anser see this:
[How do you enable mod_rewrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131236/how-do-you-enable-mod-rewrite)